# UIScrollview contentOffset is different in iOS 6 vs iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a ViewController that contains a UIScrollView with an image. The user can zoom/pan the image using the UIScrollView. After the user is done, I need to crop the image. I can do the math to find the visible rectangle using the zoomScale and contentOffset... but it doesn't work the same in iOS6 vs iOS7. If I zoom to the almost exact same spot using both versions of the simulator, and NSLog the info, this is what i get:

iOS7:

```
zoom: 2.56
content offset: {256.5, 274}
content size: {817.75256, 817.75256}
picture size: {960, 960}
scrollview bounds: {{256.5, 274}, {320, 320}}
```

iOS6:

```
zoom: 2.54
content offset: {170.5, 182}
content size: {813.26, 813.26}
picture size: {960, 960}
scrollview bounds: {{170.5, 182}, {320, 320}}
```

The zoom and content sizes are slightly different, which is fine since I am manually attempting to zoom to the same spot on both simulators. But why the massive difference in contentOffset?

Simulators used:

- Retina 3.5" 6.1
- Retina 3.5" 7.1

Also, I am using self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; for iOS7

Comment: Almost all is different between iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: Have you got scroll view delegate (or other) code you are not showing us? Show us.

Comment: Also: why is the content size different? How is it calculated / generated / set?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: please show (as part of your logging) the scroll view's bounds in both versions.

Comment: Matt, I updated the logs to include the bounds. Also, there really isn't more code related to the scrollview. I set the delegate, min/max zoom scale, etc. in Interface Builder. Also, the content size changes as I pinch/zoom. Not sure why, figured it was normal.

Comment: Why the origin of the scrollview is so different? Do you move the scrollview as well when panning?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Apparently, panning/zooming an image in a UIScrollView in iOS 6 WITH Autolayout is pretty tricky. Some workarounds need to be taken to get it working properly. The easiest thing for me was to create a separate storyboard file with Autolayout disabled, and move this view controller there. Works like a charm now.